# Getting "File google-services.json is missing" when trying to use use different json files based on the build type

Tags: android, firebase, build.gradle

On Android, I'm trying to add different google-service.json files to specific build folder:

/app/src/prod/google-service.json

/app/src/stage/google-service.json

In my gradle, I added `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`, as per the Firebase [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects#support_multiple_environments_in_your_android_application%5C).

The problem is that I get the "File missing error", because it says that those locations (Ex. /app/src/prod) is not part of the searched locations list, which I've seen from the list. How can I make it have that prod folder a part of the searched locations?

Comment: How did you configure these build types/flavors? Consider sharing the contents of your Gradle file for others to get a better view of what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you name your files `google-service.json`?

If so, try renaming them to `google-services.json` (note the pluralization of "service") and see if that works.

Comment: I'm sorry, could you clarify - are your files named `google-service.json` or `google-services.json`?